# C#. Как список методов передать в метод?

Tags: c#, razor, методы, extension

Помогите разобраться!

Есть вьюшка куда должен рендериться HTML код из HTML хелпера

```
@(Html.Extension().TabStrip()
    .Items(i =>
    {
        i.Add().Text("Tab 1").Content("Content tab 1").Selected(true).Render();
        i.Add().Text("Tab 2").Content("Content tab 2").Render();
        i.Add().Text("Tab 3").Content("Content tab 3").Render();
        i.Add().Text("Tab 4").Content("Content tab 4").Render();
    })
    .Render())
```

Как мне методы .Add().Content(). Select().Render() передать в метод .Items()

```
public SomeExtension Items(this SomeExtension @this, ...)
{
Some code...
}
```

Comment: Вообще, я не вижу прям такой особой необходимости тащить именно методы, можно передать набор { tabTitle, tabContect и isSelected }.

Comment: а можно подробнее. Спасибо! =)